# PythonAnyWhere MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

У меня есть база данных на PythonAnywhere. А также есть файл, который делает запрос

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`vk_id`, `status`) VALUES (827831, 0)
```

Запрос я проверил, то есть если его скопировать-вставить в консоль mysql, он сработает. При этом когда этот запрос выполняется в программе, он создает эту запись, но я не вижу ее через консоль, а также она удаляется после перезагрузки сервера. То есть далее в коде select считывает эту запись, прибавляется auto increment, а записи нет. Что это за "виртуальная" запись?

Comment: Может, незафиксированная транзакция? вот она и откатывается...

Comment: Что это такое? Никогда раньше не сталкивался

Comment: Сразу после своего запроса выполните запрос с единственным словом `COMMIT;`

Comment: Спасибо, все получилось!!! Буду теперь разбираться с этими транзакциями